# Place transparent overlay over entire google map (like a modal cover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Hello as the title suggests

I have a map that for the most part fills the screen besides a navigation bar that hangs on the size absolute positioned.

When a marker is clicked I have an info box popping up with location information.  I would like to put a black transparent layer behind this, over top of the map, to prevent map clicks until the close the information box.

I have tried to use custom overlays, mainly using another infobox to layer but in order to position the info box it is offsetting the top and left positions to meet the marker its supposed to cover.

So what I am stuck with right now is a black transparent box, 5000px by 5000px that appears to the bottom left of the pin.

Is there a way to set the overlay to match the google map canvas? top, left, right, bottom sides.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: api version 3 is what i am using

Comment: Thought so, have a look at my answer. If that doesn't help you if have to look deeper, because there is some code to make the overlay thing possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be a solution instead of using an overlay.
You could turn off the controls so the user can't interact with the map.

If you use:

```
map.setOptions({draggable: false, 
        zoomControl: false, 
        scrollwheel: false, 
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        mapTypeControl:false});
```

You turn off the controls on your map. Where `map` is your map object.
And whenever you close your infowindow you reverse this process to enable everything.

Comment: This in combination with a rectangle set to cover `{ north: 90, south: -90, east: 180, west: -180 }` finally solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jquery to set the top, left positions to 0 and moving the overlay to the map pane.